# Lubuntu Nginx - Phpmyadmin stuck on login

Tags: linux, nginx, phpmyadmin

I migrated from `apache2` to `Nginx` on my `Lubuntu` server.

I configured the `phpmyadmin` site as follow, and I can successfully navigate to it from `localhost:88`.

command: `sudo nano etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin`

```
server {

    server_name _;
    listen 88;
    listen [::]:88;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    allow all;

#    access_log logs/host.access.log;
#    error_log logs/host.error.log;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;

    location / {
#      root /usr/share;
#      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
#        try_files $uri $document_root$fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Even when it works going on `localhost:88` and I try to log into my console, I just get the page refreshed without any error or page change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but removing HTTPS part made it work. Now my config file looks like this:

```
server {

    server_name _;
    listen 88;
    listen [::]:88;
#    listen 443 ssl http2;
#    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    allow all;

#    access_log logs/host.access.log;
#    error_log logs/host.error.log;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;

    location / {
#      root /usr/share;
#      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
#        try_files $uri $document_root$fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
#        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
#        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows why it works now, I'm curious

Comment: @jww hi! just to know, why is it off-topic? isn't that about coding? (just to know, then I will remove that)